# NIntegrate doesn't work

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function, `Dx[s]` (defined in a module) which I can plot:

```
Plot[Dx[s], {s, 0, GetLatticeLength[]}]
```

[image]

However if I try to integrate it, I get nothing:

```
NIntegrate[Dx[s], {s, 2, 3}]
```

> > ```
> > NIntegrate[Dx[s], {s, 2, 3}]
> > ```

Note that the function has quite complicated form with many
`If`-statements, hence can't be easily represented symbolically (e.g. `Dx[a]`).
Still, for any numerical value I tried it gives a definite answer. 
Also, it seems from the plot that there are no wild singularities etc.

Why  doesn't `NIntegrate` work? Shouldn't it be just numerical evaluation
of the integrand? I mean, the plot works, why shouldn't `NIntegrate` work as well?

Comment: Try to change the definition (or redefine it as) to `Dx[a_?NumericQ]:= ...`

Comment: Dear Belisarius, thanks, it worked!